# How do I create a draggable div that only accepts one at a time

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, draggable

I am trying to make an application that uses basic block coding.
How can I make it so it only accepts one draggable at a time? And detect what draggable is in the "editor" div?

Here is where I'm at currently(Ignore the CSS, it looks better with the full dashboard):
https://jsfiddle.net/mdv16tqh/
Anybody help?

HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js"></script>    
<div class="colum">
        <div class="selection1">
            <div class="selection1-button" onclick="S1()">
                <!-- ICON -->
            </div>
            <div id="selection1-section" class="selection1-section">
                <div id="launchPad"> 
                <div style="top: 7%;" class="card"><h3 class="elem1text">WARMUP_AND_COOLDOWN</h3></div>
                <div style="top: 14%;" class="card"><h3 class="elem1text">RUN_COMMAND</h3></div>
                <div style="top: 21%;" class="card"><h3 class="elem1text">TEXT</h3></div>
                <div style="top: 28%;" class="card"><h3 class="elem1text">BROADCAST_TEXT</h3></div>
                <div style="top: 35%;" class="card"><h3 class="elem1text">ANVIL_GUI</h3></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
                
<div class="editor">
  <div class="text-editor">
    <div id="dropZone">
      <div class="stack">
        <div class="stackDrop1"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$("#launchPad").height($(window).height());
    
    $(".card").draggable({
        cursor: "move",
        helper: 'clone',
    });
    
    $("#launchPad").droppable({
        accept: ".card",
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            $("#launchPad").append($(ui.draggable));
        }
    });
    
    $(".stackDrop1").droppable({
        accept: ".card",
        drop: function(event, ui) {        
            $(this).append($(ui.draggable));
        }
    });
```

Thank you!

Comment: You probably need to have some way of storing the state of your app: Your list of cards; which one is currently being dragged; which one is currently in the text editor area etc. You should look into the MVC pattern to see how developers typically solve this kind of problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your `drop` callback, you can disable the drop after an item has been accepted.

Comment: @Twisty Hi, I need it to accept the latest one, not only the first one.

Comment: @DevSteven it will always accept the latest item dragged to it. Please clarify what you mean and be more specific.